# markup for a rounded panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I need to place a panel in the screen with border color blue, border type solid and the panel should have a rounded corner in all four edges of the panel.

Comment: do you actually want an asp.net panel control or do you just want a div with this syle applied to it?

Comment: whatever may be either panel or group box ox div, i want show rounded corner box with border color blue in the screen. coding please. moreever you can use css or anything to acheive this

Comment: "coding please" lolz.

you can use the new rounded edges feature of CSS3, but for cross-browser compatability best to use multiple images (ie top left is small round corner image, top is long straight line image, top right is small round corner image).

Answer (score 0):

asp Panels can not be rounded throw the property window, you can try on of the following:

1. Use a div with a background image (images may slow the page loading)
   2- use css and nested divs with small round corners images

Comment: give example for the above answer please

Answer (score 0):

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203225/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081104-1.aspx

This will help you..